# Upper Derivatives and Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Recall Chebyshev's Inequality:

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $E$. Then for any $\lambda > 0$,  $$m \{x \in E \mid f(x) \ge \lambda \} \le \frac{1}{\lambda } \int_{E} f$$

Here is a theorem in my book:

> Let $f$ be an increasing function on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. Then, for each $\alpha > 0$, $$m^* \{x \in (a,b) \mid \overline{D}f(x) \ge \alpha \} \le \frac{1}{\alpha} [f(b) - f(a)]$$
>
> and $$m^* \{x \in E \mid \overline{D}f(x) = \infty \} = 0$$

Note that $\overline{D} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \sup_{0 < |t| \le h } \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$. To my mind, the inequality in the above theorem bears a strong resemblance to Chebyshev's inequality. Is there any way to prove lemma 3 using Chebyshev's inequality? Of course, the first question to answer is, is $\overline{D} f(x)$ even measurable? Well, if $f$ is increasing, then $f(x+t)$ is also measurable since it is also increasing. Then $\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$ is also measurable. But it isn't clear that $\sup_{0 < |t| \le h } \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$ is measurable, nor is it clear that the limit of this (as $h \to 0$) is measurable.

Comment: All four Dini derivatives of a measurable function are measurable. See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-8474-8_4

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the link. Any ideas about the main question? That is, can Chebyshev's inequality be used to prove the inequality?